# Can't find where the mpd service is started

Tags: systemd, services, mpd

I installed `mpd` (Music Player Daemon) a long time ago on my systemd Arch Linux (I don't remember the installation/setup details).

The `mpd` server is started during boot, but I can't find where/how it is started. It may be run by my own personal init scripts, but I didn't find anything inside them.

```
$ systemctl status
[...]
   CGroup: /
           ├─user.slice
           │ └─user-1000.slice
           │   ├─user@1000.service
           │   │ ├─session.slice
           │   │ │ └─pulseaudio.service
           │   │ │   ├─2028 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal
           │   │ │   └─2072 /usr/lib/pulse/gsettings-helper
           │   │ ├─app.slice
           │   │ │ ├─mpd.service
           │   │ │ │ └─1963 /usr/bin/mpd --no-daemon
[...]

$ systemctl status mpd.service
○ mpd.service - Music Player Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:mpd(1)
             man:mpd.conf(5)
```

In the commands above, I don't understand why `systemctl status` shows that `mpd` was started from `mpd.service`, but `systemctl status mpd.service` shows that `mpd.service` is inactive/dead.

If I kill `mpd`, then start `mpd.service`, then `$ systemctl status mpd.service` shows the service as "active":

```
$ killall mpd
$ systemctl start mpd.service
$ systemctl status mpd.service
● mpd.service - Music Player Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-10-17 20:01:57 CEST; 4min 55s ago
       Docs: man:mpd(1)
             man:mpd.conf(5)
   Main PID: 4237 (mpd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18719)
     Memory: 8.9M
        CPU: 96ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mpd.service
             └─4237 /usr/bin/mpd --no-daemon

oct. 17 20:07:59 pad systemd[1]: Starting Music Player Daemon...
oct. 17 20:07:59 pad mpd[4237]: exception: bind to '0.0.0.0:6600' failed (continuing anyway, because binding to '[::]:6600' succeeded): Failed to bind socket: Address already in use
oct. 17 20:07:59 pad mpd[4237]: config: Found database setting without music_directory - disabling database
oct. 17 20:07:59 pad mpd[4237]: output: No 'audio_output' defined in config file
oct. 17 20:07:59 pad mpd[4237]: output: Successfully detected a alsa audio device
oct. 17 20:07:59 pad systemd[1]: Started Music Player Daemon.
oct. 17 20:08:00 pad mpd[4237]: avahi: Service 'Music Player @ pad' successfully established.
```

As an extra, I don't understand the error `bind to '0.0.0.0:6600' failed` above, because `lsof -i :6600` gives no output:

```
$ lsof -i :6600
$
```

Could somehow give me clues on how to find where `mpd` service is started?

Thanks in advance

Comment: mpd was started as a user service (it's in the user slice), so you need `systemctl --user status mpd.service` instead of `systemctl status mpd.service`.

Comment: @Wieland Indeed `--user` was missing, `systemctl --user status mpd.service` gives the expected result; I will edit my question soon; maybe it will just solve it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was a user service, just needed to use `systemctl --user` instead of `systemctl`.